Host name for LocalStack Redshift for Amazon Redshift JDBC driver
I have setup LocalStack in my windows machine and started with redshift and few other services.
Then I created a cluster and a DB.
>awslocal redshift describe-clusters --cluster-identifier my-cluster
{
    "Clusters": [
        {
            "ClusterIdentifier": "my-cluster",
            "NodeType": "n1",
            "ClusterStatus": "available",
            "MasterUsername": "admin",
            "DBName": "my-db",
            "Endpoint": {
                "Address": "my-cluster.cg034hpkmmjt.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com",
                "Port": 5439
            },
            ...
        }
    ]
}

It's showing my-cluster.cg034hpkmmjt.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com as the address,
So including that, I have tried following URLs but not success so far.
 1. "jdbc:redshift://localhost:4566/my-db"
 2. "jdbc:redshift://localhost:5439/my-db"
 3. "jdbc:redshift://my-cluster.cg034hpkmmjt.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com:5439/my-db"

I also tried all of these URLs in SQL client tools as well (DBeaver & SQL Workbench/J ) but couldn't connect to the DB.
But I know it's working with python clients like
AWS.Redshift in aws-sdk and boto3.client with localhost url and localstack running port.
Is there any other URL format or Port that that need to be used? or local stack is simply not supporting JDBC connections?

Please note that the free Community version of LocalStack only supports mocking of Redshift API responses, but not the actual database functionality. There's also a paid Pro version available, which you can use to enable proper emulation, including the ability to connect to the cluster/database via a JDBC driver. See here for more details: https://docs.localstack.cloud/user-guide/aws/redshift
